# Create FormArray in separate component. not updating form

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular4-forms

Hello I have searched for a day about this. I cannot seem to find a good anwser so I thought that I would post something on here. What I am trying to accomplish is that in a separate component I would like a FormArray be able to pass this in from the parent component and when that form becomes invalid it disable the parent save button.

So i started looking for this and found somewhere that did this (well with a few of my modifications it did this on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mT5kRWHm3a4DMbitbRAX?p=preview). I added this code:

```
let person = new Person();
person.name='James';
person.address=new Address();
person.address.street='123 main street';
person.address.zip = '22222';

this.myForm.reset({
  name:person.name
});
this.myForm.controls.address.reset({
  street:this.person.address.street,
  zip:this.person.address.zip
});
```

to the on init method and this:

```
<app-child [address]="myForm.controls.address"></app-child>      
<button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!myForm.valid" >save</button>
```

to the html.

I was able then to get the form to bind to the component and then the save button became disabled when it was supposed to. GREAT!

So then i started on the form array, and made a few more modifications:

in the child template i changed to:

```
<div>
   <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="add()">+</button>
   <button class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
</div>
<div formArrayName="addresses" *ngFor="let address of addresses.controls; let i=index">
  <div [formGroup]="i">
    <label>Street: </label>
    <input formControlName="street"><br>
    <label>Zip: </label>
    <input formControlName="zip">
  </div>
</div>
```

Changed AppChild to:

```
export class AppChild {

  constructor(
    private formBuilder:FormBuilder
  ){}

  @Input() addresses: FormArray;

  add():void{
    let address = this.formBuilder.group({
      street:['', Validators.required],
      zip:['']
    });
    this.addresses.push(address);
  }
}
```

and the myAppComponent now looks like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template:`

  <h3>Nested FormGroup</h3>

  <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input formControlName="name" />
    <app-child [addresses]="myForm.controls.addresses"></app-child>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onClick()">save</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <pre>Form Values: {{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
`,
})
export class App {

myForm: FormGroup

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    addresses: this.fb.array([ this.getAddress()])
  });

  let person = new Person();
  person.name='James';

  this.myForm.reset({
    name:person.name
  });
}

onClick():void{
  let a ='b';
  alert(this.myForm.valid);
}

getAddress():FormGroup{
  return this.fb.group({
    street: ['', Validators.required],
    zip: ['']
  });
}

}
```

So now I am receiving this error:

> Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

also I believe that it is no longer updating the parent form because of this error. How can I get the array to update the parent form?

any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but in case you are coming to this. You will always need a form surrounding your child component:

```
<section [formGroup]="container">
    <div>
       <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="add()">+</button>
       <button class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
    </div>
    <div formArrayName="addresses" *ngFor="let address of addresses.controls; let i=index">
      <div [formGroup]="i">
        <label>Street: </label>
        <input formControlName="street"><br>
        <label>Zip: </label>
        <input formControlName="zip">
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

And then in your child component:

```
export class AppChild {

  @Input() addresses: FormArray;

  container: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder:FormBuilder
  ){
    this.container = new FormGroup({});
  }



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.container.addControl('addresses', addresses);
  }

  add():void{
    let address = this.formBuilder.group({
      street:['', Validators.required],
      zip:['']
    });
    this.addresses.push(address);
  }
}
```

As the form array is already associated with the higher up formGroup (myForm) it will be updated in there also.